# How to use JavaScript selected functionality when particular language is selected in conjunction with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, selection

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

I have a html select box. The select box is responsible for selecting the preferred languages. for instance if a page is displayed in Germany then the select box should display Germany as its preference and likewise for the other languages.

**WHAT HAVE BEEN DONE SO FAR**

In application.html.erb I have below code

```
#application.html.erb

<select name="language" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <% @langs.each_pair do |short, long| %>
    <option value="/<%= short %>/<%= @rem %>" <% if short==@langu %> selected="selected"<% end %>><%= long %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

In application_controller.rb I have below code

```
#application_controller.rb
@string = request.fullpath
@langu  = @string.split("/")
@rem    = @string.split("/#{@langu[1]}/")
@langu  = @langu[1]
@rem    = @rem[1]

@langs = { :en => 'english', 
           :es => 'espaniol', 
           :de => 'germany', 
           :fr => 'french', 
           :it => 'italy' }
```

**WHAT IS NOT WORKING**

When user views a website in English/Spanish/Germany **OR** selects from the list, the select box evidently should show the particular language. i.e. if English then english, if Spanish then espaniol and so on. This is the exact thing not working

**WHAT IS WORKING**

If the user selects the preferred language (lets say Spanish) from the select box it renders the specific page, however the select box displays english which in essence should be `espaniol`.

Thanks!

Comment: The attribute is `selected` and not `select`. If you are in HTML5, you can omit the `selected="selected`" and just write  `selected`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typos but not working guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a minor typo in your string. It should be `selected='selected'`, so it should work like this:

```
<select name="language" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<% @langs.each_pair do |short, long| %>
<option value="/<%= short %>/<%= @rem %>" <% if @short==@langu %> selected="selected"<% end %>><%= long %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

Comment: also it is `if short==@langu` instead of `@short` [line: 3]

Comment: As a note, using `onChange` is crazy old-school. Can't you use something more civilized like jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

**BACKGROUND & SOLUTION**

OK Guys! after spending and banging my head around for not being able to find a solution to trivial matter. I finally managed to work my way around to solve the bugs. In simple words, changes were needed in application_controller.rb where my data-set values of languages (of countries) were in Hash format which actually was required to be in a Array format (look above to see the question for hash format). Along with that I had to make a slight changes on application.html.erb See below for working source code

**CHANGES MADE TO MAKE IT WORK**

- changed the **Hash** format to **Array** Format
- changed **each.pair** to only **each**

**IN application_controller.rb**

```
@langs = [['en','english'],
          ['es','espaniol'],
          ['de','germany'],
          ['fr','french'],
          ['it','italy']]
```

**IN application.html.erb**

```
<select name="language" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">    
    <% @langs.each do |short, long| %>
        <option value="/<%= short %>/<%= @rem %>" <% if short==@langu %> selected="selected" <% end %>><%= long %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

**NOTE**
Thank You to all, for your efforts to solve this bug. Hope this helps to someone in future.