# Change locale with a select_tag in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, locale, html-select

How could I change locale with a select_tag?

```
    <%= form_tag ({:action => "set_locale"}) do %>
        <%= select_tag "select_lang", options_from_collection_for_select(@languages, "two_letter_code", "name") %>
        <%= submit_tag("set language") %>
    <% end %>
```

In my applicationController I have a set_locale method:

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params.include?('locale') && !Language.where(:two_letter_code => params[:locale]).empty?
end
```

But it doesnt works...

thank you.

Comment: The links may be the solutions:
**1** [Select Function for Internationalisation API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497177/how-to-use-javascript-selected-functionality-when-particular-language-is-selecte)

**2** [Set Locale Based on Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310812/set-locale-automatically-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the parameter is a string ("en") instead of a symbol (:en). params[:locale].to_sym might help.